# Unable to install or update Ruby bluecloth gem on Windows Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bluecloth

I'm getting an error message while trying to update my version of bluecloth gem on Windows. Is there a different version that I need to install for Windows or an alternative to bluecloth that I can use? Unfortunately my development environment is strictly Windows due to other software I work with, otherwise I'd use a Linux environment.

Here's a copy paste of what I get:

> C:\Users\Developer1>gem update
>   Updating installed gems
>   Updating bluecloth
>   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing bluecloth:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   checking for srand()... yes
>   checking for random()... no
>   checking for rand()... yes
>   checking for bzero() in string.h,strings.h... no
>   checking for strcasecmp()... yes
>   checking for strncasecmp()... yes
>   checking for mkdio.h... yes
>   checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
>   creating extconf.h
>   creating Makefile
>
> make
>   C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_bluecloth_ext'"  > bluecloth_ext-i386-mingw32.def
>   gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1
>   .9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -DVERSION=\"2.0.9\" -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -I.  -o bluecloth.o -c bluecloth.c
>   In file included from c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../..
>   /../include/windows.h:48:0,
>   from c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../..
>   /../include/winsock2.h:22,
>   from c:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:33,
>   from c:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:205,
>   from c:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:74,
>   from c:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>   from bluecloth.h:14,
>   from bluecloth.c:25:
>   c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:2
>   29:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
>   c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:2
>   38:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
>   c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:2
>   38:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
>   c:\ruby-devkit\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:2
>   41:24: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
>   make: *** [bluecloth.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0 for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0/ext/gem_make.out 
>   Nothing to update

Comment: had you previously installed the gem with `gem install bluecloth`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the order in which headers are included in the C extension included in BlueCloth are blocking the compilation under Windows.

Applying the following patch:

https://gist.github.com/1539611

Compiles and works.

Perhaps you can report the issue to the gem author?

http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth
https://github.com/ged/bluecloth

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The header files in 2.2.0 prevents bluecloth from compile on windows. However, you can patch it by yourself. As Luis Lavena mentioned, you need to apply the path.

1. Run `gem install bluecloth -v '2.2.0'` if you haven't already
2. Apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/1539611) on `bluecloth.h` file, on my machine it is located in

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\ext\bluecloth.h`
3. Go to bluecloth 2.2.0 directory, for example

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0`
4. Run `rake gem` (this may require to install some additional gems).

   Then you should see .gem file created in

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\pkg\bluecloth-2.2.0.gem`
5. Open this directory and install the patched gem:

   `gem install bluecloth-2.2.0.gem --platform=ruby`

Comment: Thanks for the info but that just wiped out the gem completely from it's own directory. You didn't say copy it out first.

Comment: I applied the patch but I'm getting the same error I went looking to resolve. But unlike this topic my checks don't find some of the requirements. checking for srand()... no
checking for srandom()... no
checking for random()... no
checking for rand()... no
checking for bzero() in string.h,strings.h... no
checking for strcasecmp()... no
checking for stricmp()... no
This extension requires either strcasecmp() or stricmp() Should I reinstall the devkit and try again?