# Installing Publify with bundle install, error on bluecloth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bluecloth, publify

I'm trying to install Publify web blog CMS 6.0.9 for Ruby on Rails 3.1 on Windows.

Every time I try to `bundle install` [Publify](http://publify.co), I get the same error message when installing the bluecloth gem:

```
C:\Users\Lunasea\Downloads\typo-6.0.9>gem install bluecloth
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bluecloth:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for srand()... yes
checking for random()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for bzero() in string.h,strings.h... no
checking for strcasecmp()... yes
checking for strncasecmp()... yes
checking for mkdio.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_bluecloth_ext'"
> bluecloth_ext-i386-mingw32.def
gcc -I. -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Rails
Installer/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9
.2/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -DVERSION=\"2.0.9\"
-O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-st
rings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -I.  -o bluecloth.o -c blue
cloth.c
In file included from c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.
1/../../../../include/windows.h:48:0,
                 from c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.
1/../../../../include/winsock2.h:22,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.
h:33,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/define
s.h:205,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
:74,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from bluecloth.h:14,
                 from bluecloth.c:25:
c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../include/
windef.h:229:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../include/
windef.h:238:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../include/
windef.h:238:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
c:\railsinstaller\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../include/
windef.h:241:24: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
make: *** [bluecloth.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bluecloth
-2.2.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

I already tried to install the gem alone or simply to install the latest version, but it gives always the same result.

I'm using the standard generated database.yml.

Answer (score 5):

The header files in 2.2.0 prevents bluecloth from compile on windows. However, you can patch it by yourself:

1. Run `gem install bluecloth -v '2.2.0'` if you haven't already
2. Apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/1539611) on `bluecloth.h` file, on my machine it is located in

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\ext\bluecloth.h`
3. Go to bluecloth 2.2.0 directory, for example

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0`
4. Run `rake gem` (this may require to install some additional gems).

   Then you should see .gem file created in

   `H:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\pkg\bluecloth-2.2.0.gem`
5. Open this directory and install the patched gem:

   `gem install bluecloth-2.2.0.gem --platform=ruby`

Comment: For ppl facing error like me:
after step 4, move the contents of pkg directory to a temp dir, go to temp dir and then execute the command in step 5

Comment: Step 4 throws error - rake aborted !- posted this as a separate question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327130/ruby-error-with-installing-bluecloth-2-2-0-gem-in-win-7-ruby-1-9-3

Answer (score 2):

Windows is not the greatest environment to run rails under. This is a good example. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674826/trouble-updating-ruby-bluecloth-gem-on-windows-ruby-1-9-2) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! Could you only help me install the patch plz ? I never did it before... About the environement I know that Windows isn't the best but well I don't have a Mac and I don't really like to programm on my Linux VMWare.

Comment: I tested the patch by removing the "red" lines and adding the "green" lines in the link you provided but it doesn't worked... :S