# ruby - Error with installing bluecloth-2.2.0 gem in Win 7 , ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bluecloth

Was following steps described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13544086/3206440 for resolving error with bluecloth-2.2.0 gem installation in windows 7. Encountered an error in step 4 given in the above link - any ideas?

Console output below.

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0>rake gem
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0/Rakefile:24
: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Defaulting gemspec to MIT license.
Call license in hoe spec to change.
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task '.gemtest'

Tasks: TOP => gem => pkg/bluecloth-2.2.0.gem
(See full trace by running task with --trace)



C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0>rake gem --
trace
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0/Rakefile:24
: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Defaulting gemspec to MIT license.
Call license in hoe spec to change.
** Invoke gem (first_time)
** Invoke pkg/bluecloth-2.2.0.gem (first_time)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task '.gemtest'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_m
anager.rb:62:in `[]'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:57:in `lookup_prerequisite'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:53:in `block in prerequisite_tasks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:53:in `map'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:53:in `prerequisite_tasks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gem => pkg/bluecloth-2.2.0.gem

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0>cd ..
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a programming question. I'd suggest ask somewhere else or inspect the Rakefile why it tries invoke .gemtest target and possibly disable if not harmful.

Comment: Could you please suggest where else could this question be asked ?

Answer (score 0):

If your using Hoe then be sure to disable some of the plugins. I'm not sure which ones are enabled by default but you could certainly try that first.
[Homepage here](http://www.zenspider.com/projects/hoe.html)

I would suggest starting out with the list of them like so:
Hoe.plugins.delete :newb
and then just comment them out as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please create .gemtest folder in root of project